# Background service in Application class

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'd like to run a **service in background** but after I **read the docs** I'm a bit confused.

(I'm targeting **SdkVersion 27**, which means I can't start a `BroadcastReceiver` from the `AndroidManifest.xml` and need to do these tasks within the `Application` class, *afaik*.)

Before I was starting the `IntentService`  within a `BroadcastReceiver`, which I started by using a `PendingIntent`, which was triggered by an `AlarmManager`. It felt a bit too much, so I started the service directly on the `onCreate()` of the `Application`.

It's working, but I'm not sure if that's a **good practice**.

The service is supposed to run *forever* and fire it's own threads for operations that can take up to one minute and run again as soon as they are finished (+ 5 seconds).

**Pseudocode of the services purpose**

```
MyService // starts on Application creation an runs "forever"
    threads = []
    itemIds = []

    async loop manageThreads // start / kill
        itemIds = getItemIdsFromDatabase()

        loop itemIds vs threads
            if noThreadRunningForCurrentItemId
                threads.push(new ItemThread(itemId).start())


        loop threads vs itemIds
            if threadRunsForNoneExistingItemId
               threads[currentItemId].kill()

        sleep(20000) // manage threads every 20 seconds


    ItemThread(int itemId)
        doSomething()
        sleep(5000) 
        ItemThread(itemId) // restart thread every 5 seconds
```

I'd like to avoid that the service get's killed by Android, blocks other Threads or leads to memory leaks.

**What's the best practise for this use-case, any idea?**

*I don't think my question is opinion-based, because I guess that a pattern exists, which I'm not aware of yet.*

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Start MyService to run in the background
        Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        this.startService(service);
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    public MyService() { 
        super("MyService") 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {       
        try {
            int i = 0;
            while(true) {
                Log.d("MyService", "i = " + String.valueOf(i));
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }              
    }
}
```